# Edit Tile why this ".." is coming up? Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am editing Title.

[image]

THEN I see on my Dashboard

I am seeing this ".." ???

[image]

Where this is coming from??? How can I remove this ..

Comment: You probably got spaces or enter keys after your title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clicking "Reset" inside the "Edit Title" box and then typing your title again.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Bernardo, either spaces or enter after the title would make tableau truncate the space and use ... to indicate it's hiding the rest.